# Trying to remove list element if it's less than threshold?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
lst = ['aaaaabbbbb','yyyyaaaaaaxxx', 'eeeaaaaassaaa']
```

and I'm trying to see if between 50 to 60 percent of the list index consists of 'a'. If it doesn't, the index should be removed.

Here's what I got:

```
def remove_stuff(sequences, min_c, max_c):
   seq = cleanUp(display(sequences))   # used from another function that makes the list
   for i in seq:
        a = 'a'
        a_find = int(seq.count(a))
        length_seq = int(len(seq))
        average = ((a_find) / length_seq) * 100
        if average < min_c:
            seq.remove(i)
        elif average > max_c:
            seq.remove(i)
         else:
             pass
```

Output would be something like:

```
['aaaaabbbbb'] # only one that satisfied between 50-60%
```

How could I go about getting the new modified list?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: forgot that, let me edit

Comment: Please clarify: you need to: a) remove item from existing list **or** b) it's OK to create new list with filtered values

Answer (score 3):

```
In [2]: lst = ['aaaaabbbbb','yyyyaaaaaaxxx', 'eeeaaaaassaaa']

In [3]: lst = [i for i in lst if 0.5<i.count('a')/len(i)<0.6]

In [4]: lst
Out[4]: ['aaaaabbbbb']
```

Comment: Note that you are creating **new** list and OP wrote: 'index should be removed'

Comment: I reinitialize the list with the new list.

Comment: @AlexYu: Check the edited question. The OP wants a new list. You can of course assign the same name

Comment: @Bazingaa it's not clear for me what OP means with "new modified list" - is it **"new"**? If so - why **"modified"**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter for that:

```
def condition_a(elem):
    count_of_a = elem.count('a')
    rate_of_a = count_of_a / len(elem)
    return 0.5 <= rate_of_a <= 0.6

lst = ['aaaaabbbbb','yyyyaaaaaaxxx', 'eeeaaaaassaaa']
list(filter(condition_a, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method to keep elements based on condition (predicate):

```
def keep_if(predicate, iterable):
  for element in iterable:
    if predicate(element):
      yield element
```

Then define a method to test the condition:

```
def is_between_50_60_percent(letter, string):
  perc = string.count(letter) / len(string)
  return perc >= 0.5 and perc <= 0.6
```

Given your list:

```
lst = ['aaaaabbbbb','yyyyaaaaaaxxx', 'eeeaaaaassaaa']
```

**Finally you can just call:**

```
keep_if( lambda x: is_between_50_60_percent('a', x), lst)
```

---

```
res = keep_if( lambda x: is_between_50_60_percent('a', x), lst)
print(list(res)) #=> ['aaaaabbbbb']
```